# Sumar valores de dos tablas diferentes segun id seleccionado

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla "inventory_ticket" esta tiene quantityTicket, y la tabla "inventory_list", lo que quiero hacer es un query que me permita sumar las cantidades de las dos tablas pero segun el id seleccionado que esta como fk_inventory en "inventoy_Ticket"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado esto:

```
select (
    (select sum(quantityTicket) from quantityTicket) +
    (select sum(quantity) from inventory_list) 
where fk_Inventory = 108
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error diciendo que mi sintaxis es incorrecta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que llevas hasta el momento?

Comment: Por favor comparte el código que has intentado ejecutar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No esta claro que queres unir con que. Que intentaste hasta ahora? podes explicar que son esas dos imagenes? podes agregar datos para probar? cual es la salida esperada? cual la salida actual?

Comment: Puedes usar el operador union. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Quieres sumar las cantidades que hay en las 2 tablas, quantityTicket en una y quantity en la otra es eso????

Comment: La relacion entre las 2 tablas con que campos se hace, fk_inventory con que campo de la otra tabla se relaciona, normalmente deberia ser el id pero no veo ese campo en la otra tabla????

Comment: el campo con la que se relaciona es numFile,disculpa...

Comment: es de uno a uno o de 1 a muchos esa relación???

Comment: Tienes un fallo tipográfico: te falta el cierre de un paréntesis (he editado el código para que sea más fácil de leer y el error es más obvio). Eso va a hacer que recibas el error que estás recibiendo (luego puede haber otros errores, pero ese es el que te está dando fallo ahora mismo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
select sum( (select 
sum(quantity) from inventory_list ) + (select sum(quantityTicket) from quantityTicket where fk_Inventory = 108 )) as "sum"
```

1. en tu query te falta un parentesis
2. selecciona pero no sumas
3. el fk_Inventory =108 lo pones global y ambas tablas no lo tienen!

Comment: siempre agrega una explicación para saber que cambiaste y que el OP debe mejorar

Comment: Gracias, esto me ayudo con mi problema, y disculpen estoy aprendiendo a usar la pagina ☻